# Using python requests and bs4 to get all the hyperlinks in a table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

There is a table on this website `https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures`. The table class id is cross_rate_1.

I am trying to get all the hyperlinks associated with each item in the table's title located at //*[@id="cross_rate_1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a.

The location of the tag for each item is `td class="bold left plusIconTd noWrap elp"` and within that it's at `a title` and `href`.

I tried the following code

```
urlheader = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

url = "https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures"
req = requests.get(url, headers=urlheader)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', id="cross_rate_1")
```

But I only get the table itself, I also tried,

```
links= soup.findAll("td", { "class" : "href" },)
```

But it comes up blank.

How do I create a table that looks like this:

```
Commodity  Hyperlink 
Gold       https://www.investing.com/commodities/gold
XAU/USD    https://www.investing.com/currencies/xau-usd
.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlheader = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

url = "https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures"
req = requests.get(url, headers=urlheader)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', id="cross_rate_1")

for a in table.findAll('a'):
    text = a.text
    url = a.get("href")
    print(text, url)
    # Or do what you want
```

Comment: For that particular question. The key point is to figure out the meaning of `curr_id` and `smlID`. Well, that's not a programming question but a... Um... another kind of question. Actually you can find the `smlID` on the page at least.

Comment: where? i cant see it anywhere except in the response header